# Not able to install packages h2osteam

Tags: r, h2o

I installed the package many times and different versions too. But it still says 
`Error in library(h2osteam) : there is no package called ‘h2osteam’`

After installation it says 
`** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded
* DONE (h2osteam)`

What am I doing wrong here? help!

Comment: Also, what version of R are you running?  h20steam isn't available for 3.6.1 (the most recent as of writing).

Comment: @Greg `R version 3.2.3 (2015-12-10) -- "Wooden Christmas-Tree"`

Comment: @MrFlick I downloaded `h2osteam_1.4.10.tar.gz` and then in R `install.packages("h2osteam_1.4.10.tar.gz", repos = NULL)`. I tried 4.8 - 4.10 all were `* DONE (h2osteam)`